# Driving with low power steering fluid

Tags: power-steering, power-steering-fluid

Was topping off my windshield wiper fluid this morning and I noticed that the power steering fluid was under the low marking, will anything happen if I continue driving?

Answer (score 1):

At best you'll damage the power steering pump.

At worst it may fail unexpectedly and you will lose power steering which makes it difficult to steer.  That may cause an accident.

Why don't you just top-off the fluid and save yourself the risk?